# Architecture of Push Notification Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am pretty confused about channel name in windows phone push notification service .

I read it from this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx

My question is- 
How to choose Channel name ? Any guide line for this. I read this link too but this is related to windows 8 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761462.aspx

And Can any one please explain me the detail architecture of windows phone 8 push notification

Comment: Channelname seems to be quite important. Just use your app-name and you should be fine. What exactly do you want to know about it? The page you linked is not too bad.

Comment: Yeah but Microsoft didn't explained much about MPNS architecture. For example I found explanation of GCM by google is very much satisfactory so I just want to know the inside implementation of MPNS like GCM